# ant-metricstask.jar

Tags: ant, metrics

Warning : since version 1.3.6 the anttask.jar as been renamed ant-metricstask.jar

As of version 1.3.2 the metrics plugin contains some ant tasks that can be used for headless operations as part of a nightly build for example. This section describes how to do this.

Where can i get it? I can not find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for ant-metricstask.jar?

It's available in the eclipse plugin downloadable at 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/metrics/files/

Point eclipse directly at the URL or download the updatesite_1.3.6.zip and you can get the jar inside.